# convert stringformat 1 Jan 22 to datet 2022-01-01

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I receive data from one of our partners with a column named `"strip"` (not sure of that matters) of type `varchar(MAX)` that contains dates in the form of: `01 Jan 22` and I need to change it to a `date` in SQL Server.

This works:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, strip, 102) as Date
```

This also works:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, strip, 106) as Date
```

However these options no longer work when I try to use this in the `WHERE` statement with the error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I'm stumped to be honest.

Comment: You're clearly getting invalid data.

Comment: If both of those work in the `SELECT` they would work in the `WHERE` (assuming you are omitting the alias), meaning that either they *didn't* work (for the whole set) or you aren't doing the same thing.

Comment: use [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to identify bad data

Comment: You should do a select on your table and check if really every row has a date within this column. My first guess would be the column is nullable and contains null values. The second guess would be it's not nullable, but contains some other strings then dates. It would be much better to define the column as datetime instead of converting it unless there is a really important reason to do not defining it as datetime.

Comment: If it's `NULL` the OP wouldn't be getting a conversion error, @JonasMetzler . A `NULL` can be converted to *any* data type; thought he value would still be `NULL`.

Comment: Ok, sorry for not pointing this out, but a varchar column can of course contain other strings then dates which let such a conversion fail, that's why I proposed to define it as datetime if possible.

Comment: Try with this: `SET LANGUAGE us_english`

Comment: Thank you for the large number of replies! I will try everything suggested and report back. One thing up-front @JonasMetzler is we receive the data from the data broker with the date filled in as Varchar(MAX). I was instructed to read the received data into the database 1:1 and do any necessary modifications in the queries to the table. I'm aware this not ideal but this is out of my hands.

Comment: @smvenk `SET LANGUAGE us_english` didn't fix my issue. But thank you!

Comment: @Squirrel `TRY_CONVERT` solved my issue! Weirdly enough though when I try: `WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DATE, strip, 106) = NULL` 0 records show up. My understanding is that `TRY_CONVERT` returns `NULL` when the conversion fails.

Comment: Try `IS NULL` not `= NULL`.

Comment: 20+ years after Y2K - NO ONE should ever be using or storing 2 digit years. You need to have a serious discussion with "partner".

Comment: @SMor I will let them know of my troubles :)

Comment: @Squirrel If you post your answer as an answer to the question instead of a comment, I will vote it up.